# systemctl enable is not working, producing Invalid argument

Tags: rabbitmq, systemctl

While running systemctl enable  i am getting :`Operation failed: Invalid argument`

```
root@1cdef67221f3:/etc/rabbitmq# systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
Operation failed: Invalid argument
```

Here is the systemctl details:

```
    root@1cdef67221f3:/etc/rabbitmq# systemctl --version
    systemd 204
    +PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ
    root@1cdef67221f3:/etc/rabbitmq# systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled
    syslog.service                enabled
    remote-fs.target              enabled
```

Here is rabbitmq details:

```
        root@1cdef67221f3:/etc/rabbitmq# rabbitmq-server

                  RabbitMQ 3.2.4. Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.
      ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
      ##  ##
      ##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log
      ######  ##        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit-sasl.log
      ##########
                  Starting broker... completed with 0 plugins.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
systemctl enable rabbitmq-server.service
```

Comment: root@1cdef67221f3:/etc/rabbitmq# systemctl enable rabbitmq-server.service
Operation failed: No such file or directory

Comment: NOTE:I am using docker ubuntu14.04

Answer (score 0):

Remove Alias line from the [Install] section